# Chrome alerts and tab activation

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tabs

I have noticed that in Chrome if I launch an alert via javascript:

```
alert("Something happened!");
```

This will activate the tab hosting the page on which the alert was fired.  I don't want this- is there a way to get more of an IE like behavior?  What I want is that if I have 10 tabs, and one of them fires an alert (after some long running process for example) that it just flashes or notifies me without taking me away from my current tab.

Ideally user configuration of something in chrome?  Or maybe an extension is needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only one way to have control on the tabs in Chrome is via an extension. I don't think that there is a method to just blink the tab or something like that. There is a function highlight https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-highlight

Comment: Well that's too bad it's not configurable... ah well, time to play with the extension :)